# Convert UTC timestamp to time with offset in Java

Tags: java

I have a MYSQL UTC timestamp "2021-07-23 08:13:17".

I want to convert this to a time with offset eg "2021-07-21T08:13:17+01:00". My code is:

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-07-23 08:13:17", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
offsetDateTime.format(ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME).toString();
```

However, the first line gives the error:

```
Text '2021-07-23 08:13:17' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2021-07-23T08:13:17 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

How can I do this simple conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Your string doesn't have a offset in it, so it's not an `OffsetDateTime`. It only has a date and a time component, so it's just a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-07-23 08:13:17", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

After that, you can give it an offset using `atOffset`:

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = localDateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no offset in your `String`, that means you will have to parse it to a `LocalDateTime` (a *DateTime* without an offset) and then add the desired offset.

This code does exactly that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = "2021-07-23 08:13:17";
    // define the formatter for parsing
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                                        Locale.ENGLISH);
    // then parse to a LocalDateTime and add an offset of +1 hour
    OffsetDateTime odt = LocalDateTime.parse(input, dtf)
                                      .atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1));
    System.out.println(odt);
}
```

Output:

```
2021-07-23T08:13:17+01:00
```